# How do I show homotopy equivalence between two topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Are two topological spaces homotopically equivalent if they are homeomorphic? If one is a deform retract of the other? Is there a way to use quotient spaces here or is that something else?

Comment: If they are homeomorphic, they are certainly homotopy equivalent (Why? Try to prove this, it is a two line proof). If one is a deformation retract of the other, same thing (Try to prove this, again, a short proof). In general, this is a VERY hard question to answer.

Comment: Hint: If you know that two topological spaces $X,Y$ are homeomorphic, then you know that there is a homeomorphism $f : X \to Y$. If you wish to prove that $X,Y$ are homotopy equivalence, you must define a homotopy equivalence $g : X \to Y$. Based on what you know, what's your best guess for defining $g$? (And similarly if $Y$ is a deformation retract of $X$).

Comment: Oh, all right, thanks. If one space is a quotient space of the other, are they also homotopically equivalent?

Comment: @JohnH. Maybe you can try to find a counterexample, or if you can't find a counterexample, try to find a proof. You may not have been introduced to them yet, but there are things called 'homotopy invariants' of topological spaces, which can be used to distinguish between spaces which are not homotopy equivalent. If you know any (such as the fundamental group, the Euler charcateristic, or homology) you may like to play around with them to find a counterexample.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the point made by the question is: how to construct homotopy equivalences which are not just homeomorphisms or deformation retracts?

A useful way is a **glueing theorem for homotopy equivalences**, published in 1968, now available in Chapter 7, "Cofibrations", of  the book [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html). See also further details and references in this [mathoverflow discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96071/general-gluing-theorem-for-adjunction-spaces).

I found this result in the 1960s through generalising the result that a homotopy equivalence of spaces $f:Y \to Z $ induces an isomorphism of homotopy groups $\pi_n(Y,y) \to \pi_n(Z,f(y))$. The proof of that involves operation of the fundamental groupoid on homotopy groups at various base points. So I looked at generalising from $(S^n,1)$ to $(X,A)$, in order to see what was going on.